# Is it possible to inject a code block without create a component in vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In a v-data-table I need to customize some rows changing the background-color and appling a tooltip. Because of the tooltip my actual solution is to write double the tr content code, one for the normal visualization and one in the template tag of the tooltip. My code:

```html
<v-data-table
  class="elevation-1"
  fixed-header
  height="600"
  item-key="id"
  :footer-props="{
    'items-per-page-all-text': $t('all'),
    'items-per-page-options': availableItemsPerPage,
    'items-per-page-text': $t('adminStrings.usersPerPage'),
    'page-text': elementCounter,
    'show-current-page': true,
    'show-first-last-page': true
  }"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="users"
  :items-per-page="paginatorData.itemsPerPage"
  :no-data-text="$t('dataNotFound')"
  :page="paginatorData.page"
  :server-items-length="totalItems"
  @update:items-per-page="itemsPerPageChanged"
  @update:page="pageChanged"
>
  <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
    <tr
      class="user-row"
      v-for="item in items"
      v-if="!isCoachingWithoutCoach(item)"
      :key="item.id"
    >
      <td class="v-data-table__divider" v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value">
        [... 12 div, one for each header with v-if|v-else-if ...]
      </td>
    </tr>
    <v-tooltip v-else top>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <tr class="no-coach-item-class" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
          <td class="v-data-table__divider" v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value">
            [... same divs as before ...]
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <span>{{ $t('noCoachMessage') }}</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Is there a way to write only the td contents in a separate file/template and inject it? If not, is there a best approach to achive what I need?
What written is the main task; under there are two extras, if you like to answer them also will be very glad.

EXTRA 1: even if this code works well, eslint (and the vue best practis) says that v-if in conjunction with v-for shouldn't been use but I cannot wrap a tr in a div so, is there a solution to this?

EXTRA 2: inside a `td > div` content I have some buttons wrapped in tooltips and eslit says that the variables `on` and `attrs` are just defined in a parent directive but if I omit those variables the tooltip won't work. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Move <td> dupe piece of code to a separate comp. That's the perfect reasoning for a new comp. If it's recurring situation then probably make a comp that conditionally wraps a slot with v-tooltip like you did. "says that v-if in conjunction with v-for shouldn't been use" - there's no such rule in general, if it's eslint rule then disable it, as long as you're aware of the consequences. "Any idea?" - don't use eslint rules that disturb you, it's up how it's configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved quite all problems following @Estus Flask solution, so I make a new component that wraps the tds. This solves everithing but v-for/v-if on the same element. I solved this by disable eslint on that tag.
Correct code now is:

```
<!-- eslint-disable -->
<tr
  class="user-row"
  v-for="item in items"
  v-if="!isCoachingWithoutCoach(item)"
  :key="item.id"
>
<!-- eslint-enable -->
  <admin-user-col-block
    v-for="column in headers"
    :can-do-act-as="canDoActAs(item)"
    :column="column"
    :headers="itemHeaders"
    :key="column.value"
    :item="item"
    @doActAs="doActAs"
    @editUser="editUser"
    @openHyerarchyManagement="openHyerarchyManagement"
    @toggleUser="toggleUser"
  />
</tr>
<v-tooltip top v-else>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <tr class="no-coach-item-class" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
      <admin-user-col-block
        v-for="column in headers"
        :can-do-act-as="canDoActAs(item)"
        :column="column"
        :headers="itemHeaders"
        :key="column.value"
        :item="item"
        @doActAs="doActAs"
        @editUser="editUser"
        @openHyerarchyManagement="openHyerarchyManagement"
        @toggleUser="toggleUser"
      />
    </tr>
  </template>
  <span>{{ $t("adminStrings.noCoachMessage") }}</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

and the AdminUserColBlock component:

```
<template>
  <td class="v-data-table__divider">
    <!-- Active -->
    <div v-if="column.value == 'active'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      <v-chip :color="item.active ? '' : 'red'" outlined>
        {{ $t(item.active ? "adminStrings.yes" : "adminStrings.no") }}
      </v-chip>
    </div>
    <!-- Branches -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'branches'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      <v-chip
        class="branch-chips"
        outlined
        v-for="(branch, idx) in item.branches"
        :class="getBranchChipClass(branch, idx, item.branches)"
        :color="getBranchColor(branch)"
        :key="branch.id"
        @click.stop="openHyerarchyManagement(branch)"
      >
        {{ branch.name }}
      </v-chip>
    </div>
    <!-- Commands -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'commands'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      <div class="ai-center d-flex">
        <!-- Act as -->
        <div class="mr-1">
          <v-tooltip top>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                color="red"
                fab
                outlined
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                x-small
                :disabled="!canDoActAs"
                @click="doActAs(item)"
              >
                <v-icon>mdi-drama-masks</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>{{ $t("adminStrings.actAs") }}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </div>
        <!-- Edit user -->
        <div class="mr-1">
          <v-tooltip top>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                color="primary"
                fab
                outlined
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                x-small
                @click="editUser(item)"
              >
                <v-icon>mdi-account-edit</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>{{ $t("adminStrings.editUser") }}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </div>
        <!-- Disable/Enable user -->
        <div class="mr-1">
          <v-tooltip top>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                dark
                fab
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                x-small
                :color="item.active ? 'red' : 'green'"
                @click="toggleUser(item)"
              >
                <v-icon v-if="item.active">mdi-account-cancel</v-icon>
                <v-icon v-else>mdi-account-reactivate-outline</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span v-if="item.active">{{ $t("adminStrings.disableUser") }}</span>
            <span v-else>{{ $t("adminStrings.enableUser") }}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Coach -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'coach' && item.coach.id" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      {{ item.coach.id }} - {{ item.coach.fullName }}
    </div>
    <!-- Creator -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'creator'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      {{ item.creator.id }} - {{ item.creator.fullName }}
    </div>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'email'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      {{ item.email }}
    </div>
    <!-- End Date -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'endDate'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      {{ dayjs(item.endDate).format("L") }}
    </div>
    <!-- Exceded Users -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'excededUsers'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      <v-icon color="red" v-if="item.excededUsers">mdi-close</v-icon>
      <v-icon color="green" v-else>mdi-check</v-icon>
    </div>
    <!-- Full Name -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'fullName'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      {{ item.fullName }}
    </div>
    <!-- Id -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'id'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      {{ item.id }}
    </div>
    <!-- Level -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'level'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      {{ $t("adminStrings." + globals.getContractLevel(item.level)) }}
    </div>
    <!-- Start Date -->
    <div v-else-if="column.value == 'startDate'" :class="'text-' + column.alignCol">
      {{ dayjs(item.startDate).format("L") }}
    </div>
  </td>
</template>
```

Also thanks to @Mortiz Ringler but your solution is more complex, this is the only thing that made me choose Estus one. Thanks also for the link to the migration guide, very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid overriding the v-data-table altogether, as it diminishes its usefulness. Let me propose two alternatives:

1. You could create the v-tooltips outside the table, and then bind them to the rows using the [`:activator`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-activator) and the [`:attach`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-attach) props. For this to work, you also need to set a class on each row so that tooltips can be assigned, which can be done using the v-data-table's [`:item-class`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-item-class) property.

   It is a bit hacky and it produces invalid HTML, same as your original code (invalid child element for tr). Also, generating all tooltips for a large set of items is not great, though you could be clever about that and use v-data-table events. Still, I think it gives you more manageable code. Have a look at the snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      headers: [{text: 'ID', value: 'id'}, {text: 'name', value: 'name'}],
      users: Array.from({length: 50}, (_,i) => ({id: i, name: 'user ' + i})),
      usersWithTooltip: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isCoachingWithoutCoach(user){
     return user.id %2 === 0
    },
    getTooltipClass(user){
      return this.isCoachingWithoutCoach(user) ? `tooltip-${user.id}` : null
    },
    async setTooltips(users){
      await this.$nextTick() // make sure rows are rendered
      this.usersWithTooltip = users.filter(this.isCoachingWithoutCoach.bind(this))
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-data-table
        item-key="id"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        :item-class="getTooltipClass"
        @current-items="setTooltips"
      >
      </v-data-table>

    <v-tooltip
      v-for="user in usersWithTooltip"
      :key="user.id"
      :activator="'.' + getTooltipClass(user)"
      :attach="'.' + getTooltipClass(user)"
      bottom
    >
      <span>Tooltip message {{user.name}}</span>
    </v-tooltip>

    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

2. This depends on your use-case and specifications, but it looks like the tooltip should warn the user of missing assignments. But to find those, the user has to hover the whole table to see if a tooltips pops up, which is usually not desired and would not work on mobile. Also, constant popups can obstruct when working with the table. Instead, you could set a small icon, and the tooltip only clarifies what the icon means.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      headers: [{text: 'ID', value: 'id'}, {text: 'name', value: 'name'}, {text: '', value: 'no-coach', width: 0}],
      users: Array.from({length: 50}, (_,i) => ({id: i, name: 'user ' + i}))
    }
  },
  computed: {
    usersWithoutCoach(){
      return this.users.filter(this.isCoachingWithoutCoach.bind(this))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isCoachingWithoutCoach(user){
     return user.id %2 === 0
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-data-table
        item-key="id"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
      >
        <template #item.no-coach="{item}">
          <v-tooltip bottom
            v-if="isCoachingWithoutCoach(item)"
          >
            <template #activator="{on, attrs}">
              <v-icon
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                color="purple"
              >mdi-account-alert</v-icon>
            </template>
            <span>Tooltip message {{item.name}}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>

    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps!

---

Oh, as to `v-if` and `v-for` on the same element, the big issue is that you rely on the precedence of `v-for` over `v-if` (since you use the variable from the loop in the if). However, this has changed in Vue 3, so migrating would break your code. Due to those issues, it is not recommended to use both on the same element, but that doesn't mean you mustn't do it. [The migration guide on the topic](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-if-v-for.html) might be helpful.